# Permanently saving a cookie in ios8

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, cookies

Is there a way to permanently save a cookie in ios8?

So I can clear every other cookie and browsing data but that cookie?

My banking makes me confirm the computer/phone I'm using through email and code, I have to do this each time, only if the cookie is deleted.

I'm using the iPhone 6 no jailbreak.

Comment: Is it possible if I jailbreak my phone?

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no way to do this through the standard user interface.  Sorry.  I can understand why you might want to do this, but the reality is that -- for pragmatic reasons -- software designers often need to keep it simple and avoid features that only a tiny fraction of their user base will use.

Comment: This is not a complex feature; it would be very simple to do for the user if one had access to the location where cookies are saved. I don't have an iPhone but I think that you cannot simply access the filesystem – at least without jailbreak.

Comment: @oarfish, I'm afraid this is not the right place to debate or discuss whether developers *should* implement such a feature.  (This is not a discussion forum.  If you're new to Stack Exchange sites, I encourage you to visit the help center on the upper-right to learn more!)  You asked whether the feature exists; that's a relevant question, and it's now been answered.

Comment: I am aware of that and did not try to start a discussion. I was merely remarking on an aspect of your answer which I find incorrect. Also, I did not ask this question.

Answer (score -1):

This let's you delete individual cookies, not a direct answer to your question but hope it helps -

http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/10/delete-site-specific-cookies-ios/

Regards

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.